# tcb/shadow is not known

Tags: tcolorbox

I've installed the latest version of `pgf` and `tcolorbox` but I still get an error :

```
I do not know the key 'tcb/shadow'...
```

The following is the first part of the preamble

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
%\usepackage{tkz-arith}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-tukey}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows}
\usepackage{mdframed, graphicx, xkeyval,ifthen, ifpdf, etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{alterqcm}


\usepackage{mdframed, graphicx, xkeyval,ifthen, ifpdf, etoolbox,fp,calc}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{%essai commande de sous-titre
  \usepackage{titling}
  \posttitle{%
    \par\large#1\end{center}}
}

\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\diamond$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=Blue,
            urlcolor=Blue,
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
```

And here is the code for a `\newcommand` which uses `tcolorbox`

```
\newcommand{\imps}[2]{%
\tcbset{skin=enhanced,colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=beamer,shadow={2mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{gris0!80!white},width=#1cm]
#2.
\end{tcolorbox}
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

TeXwriter 1.6.9 : Android

An error occures using the option "most" or "all"
   Here is a shorter  document to help you.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,a5paper,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\definecolor{gris}{gray}{.80}
\newcommand{\imps}[2]{%
\tcbset{skin=enhanced,colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=beamer,shadow={2mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{gris!80!white},width=#1cm]
#2.
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\imps{4}{L'abscisse figure toujours en première position et l'ordonnée en seconde position}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a  complete document, not only fragments. The package is called `tcolorbox`, not `tcbcolor`. The whole preamble is quite messy. Isolating the `tcolorbox` call it works (apart from the unknown color 'gris')

Comment: have you tried `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` or (overkill) `\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}`, for example?

Comment: @cmhughes: It should work with the `skins` library already (which is loaded according to the code)

Comment: @cmhughes yes but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Thanks for your quick answer I have posted a new shorter document. It doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I only get the error when compiling with TeX Live 2012: the `shadow` key has been added some time between 2012 and 2014. You should upgrade your TeX distribution. If TeXwriter doesn't support newer versions of TeX Live, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extract from the `CHANGELOG` file in the sources for `tcolorbox`:

```
version 2.31 (2013/06/18)
- several internal changes
[...]
- new shadow features for the 'skins' library with the options:
  'shadow', 'fuzzy shadow', 'drop shadow', 'drop fuzzy shadow', 'halo', 'fuzzy halo'
```

Indeed, if I compile your example with TeX Live 2013, I get no error; the error appears when I compile with TeX Live 2012.

Thus it appears that the TeX distribution shipped with your version of TeX Writer is quite old. I don't think you can upgrade just the TeX distribution without a (paid) yearly subscription to TeX Writer; however, in the developer’s site there’s no indication of what is the currently shipped version of TeX Live, so it’s best to ask the developer before paying.

Comment: You ' re absolutly right.  I also have red about the changelog and thought to the same conclusion. I will ask  the developper and post the solution if there is one.

Comment: According to the developper TeXwriter 1.6.9 is based on texlive 2013. It's planed to update in the new year, but not very soon.

Comment: In fact the developper himself said that tex writer for android is using an old version of latex, but they are going to use the latest version on the next update. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: In fact I wanted to get a shade effect inside a box of mines. With tikz I get what I wish :  `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [copy shadow={fill=blue,shadow xshift=0.5ex,shadow yshift=-0.5ex},rounded corners=3pt,
            shade,top color=green!40 ,draw=blue,thick,text width=#1cm] {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}` in the definition of the newcommand `\imps`